# Child of UI element does not change localPostion when parent change position at runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity UI.

I have a parent that includes an Image and a child Image- all inside a canvas of course.

I am using the child image position to spawn enemy from the parent.

When i move at run-time the parent image and look at inspector i expected to see the child position also move with parent (so it would spawn enemies at correct position), but it doesn't.

The child image does move with parent at scene view, but LocalPostion of RectTransform of child doesn't change with parent so i can't spawn at correct position.

I guess i am missing something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local position of any element in the scene is relative to its parent's position, that's what "local" means.

The final world position of an element is its local position relative to it's parents world position.

Assuming no rotation/scaling is involved, then world positions are defined as:

```
transform.position = transform.parent.position + transform.localPosition
```

So what you are seeing is what is to be expected.

Comment: Yeah, it worked, thanks!.. From some reason i add a memory that position of child should update based on parent position without needing the code part you wrote.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [`transform.TransformPoint()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html). Useful if there are several levels of hierarchical parentage and you want to get all the way back to scene-space coordinates.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, you don't need to add that code from my answer anywhere, Unity does this automatically in the background for all elements. I just wrote that to explain how it works.

Comment: Well Draco18s, actually the definition in my answer already considers all levels up to the root, because it considers the parent's world position, which recursively depends on their parent's world position and so on. TransformPoint() is useful because it also considers rotation and scale.